# strange ouput from regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl

So am trying to get all the matches for a regex in perl but the output is mixed with strange values?
This is my perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
my $filename="test.txt";

my $data;
open($data,$filename) or die "couldn't open the file";
while(<$data>)
{
chomp($_);


my @count = ($_ =~ /(((\d){1,4}(\s|\-|\.|\/)){1,3}(\d){2,4})/g);

print @count;

print "\n";
}
```

And the content of my text file is as following :

```
content 10-12-2015
content 10 12 2015
content 10-12-2015
content 10/12/2015
content 10.12.2015
content 10.12.15
content 10.12.1412
content 1992.12.30
content 22/04/96
content 1996-04-22
content 22.04.96
content 10.12.1412
content 1992.12.30
content 22/04/96
content 04/22/96
```

the really weird output am getting is the matched regex and other values? in the array.

```
10-12-201512-2-5
10 12 201512 2 5
10-12-201512-2-5
10/12/201512/2/5
10.12.201512.2.5
10.12.1512.2.5
10.12.141212.2.2
1992.12.3012.2.0
22/04/9604/4/6
1996-04-2204-4-2
22.04.9604.4.6
10.12.141212.2.2
1992.12.3012.2.0
22/04/9604/4/6
04/22/9622/2/6
```

An example of a normal output would be : 10-12-2015 but where did this value come from 12-2-5 ? 
The problem is that in my other text file i have more than one date in a line which means i can't only get the first match from the array .

pls help . . . . ! am new to Perl and this is killing me !

Comment: See this [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/ZOfyWR). You are quantifying a capture group (1) and you are placing a capture group on a single character pattern then quantify it (2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where did this value come from 12-2-5 ?

Since you are using **nested capturing groups** It's capturing individual parts.

From `10-12-2015` it's capturing `12-` `2` `-` `5` which is reflected in your result after **complete capture** of `10-12-2015`. Same goes for every instance.

To extract only dates you can use this regex.

**Regex:** `(?:\d{2}|\d{4})[-\/\.\s]\d{2}[-\/\.\s](?:\d{4}|\d{2})`

This regex does not use **capturing groups**.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vM6qU2/3)**

Comment: my regex works fine with the dates as i also have different dates format and different regex. My problem relays on perl and the output i get when i use these regex. Also i actually tested this regex using similar website and i got the expected matches .

Comment: @FahadAlkamli: I have added what was happening with your regex and also added a solution which does not uses capturing groups.

Comment: OMG i was trying to cover as many formates as possible and i end up doing something really stupid ! Thanks man you saved my life !

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late but using noobs regex capture group your code could look like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
my $filename="file.txt";

my $data;
open($data,$filename) or die "couldn't open the file";
while (my $line = <$data>){
    chomp($line);
    my (@count) = $line =~ /((?:\d{2}|\d{4})[-\/\.\s]\d{2}[-\/\.\s](?:\d{4}|\d{2}))/g;

    print join(" : ", @count);

    print "\n";
}
```

output

```
10-12-2015
10 12 2015 : 10.12.2015 : 11-23-2014
10-12-2015
10/12/2015
10.12.2015
10.12.15
10.12.1412 : 10.12.1412
1992.12.30
22/04/96
1996-04-22
22.04.96
10.12.1412
1992.12.30 : 10.12.2015
22/04/96
04/22/96
```

Comment: Actually your code helped me to solve another problem ! so nothing is too late ! thanks man

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using so much grouping with your regexp when you are not interested in the values.

Every opening `(` is contributing a value into the result list.

You might use the following slightly resexp to minimize the groupings and only have to deal with 2 values per match:

```
$_ =~ /((\d{1,4}[\s.\\-]){1,3}\d{2,4})/g
```

Comment: Yeah seems like i was trying to be smart but instead i was being stupid ,Thanks man !